# Is it possible to disassembly monomac file?

Tags: .net, osx-mountain-lion, monomac, disassembly

I am trying to disassembly my monomac .net exectuable file with .NET Reflactor app but it appears it is only recognizes Windows exectuables.

Is there any application/plugin which can make this thing work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

.NET reflector works on any .NET executable (.exe) or library (.dll). A MonoMac-based application will produce them (they are the output of the C#, or any other .NET, compiler) so **it will work too**.

OTOH MonoMac also produce an application bundle (a `.app` directory) and a **native** *wrapper* launcher (that replaces `mono` to launch the `.exe`). Other **native** libraries can also be included into the application bundle (so the application can be redistributed without dependencies).

Those **native** files (and directories) are not .NET executable and .NET reflector (or similar tools) won't be able to process them.